# How to execute DDLs conditionally in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a script that creates a lot of tables, indexes, triggers etc. And I want to run all those DDLs conditionally. i tried to wrap the script with 'if then' but it didn't work

```
IF exists (select 1 from xxx where yyy) THEN

    create table...

    create table...

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...

    CREATE TRIGGER ...

END IF;
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways:

```
begin
    for cur in (select 1 from xxx where yyy and rownum <= 1) loop
     execute immediate 'create table...';
     execute immediate 'create table...';
     execute immediate 'create unique index...';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

P.S. One more way is to generate exception and proceed in SQL*Plus.

file example.sql:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT;

VAR x NUMBER
EXEC :x := &1
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN (SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE 1=:x) LOOP
    RETURN;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
END;
/

PROMPT Here we are
```

Result:

```
SQL> @example
Enter value for 1 1: 1

PL/SQL procedure completed.


PL/SQL procedure completed.

Here we are
SQL> @example
Enter value for 1: 2

PL/SQL procedure completed.

BEGIN
*
error in line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: in line 5
```

When I use value 2 the block raises exception and the script exists SQL*Plus.

P.S. One more example in response - hope this cleas questions below. I create table only when it does not exist. Table containts 1024 partitions and ' characters in DEFAULT statement. Text size > 32K.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2   sql_code clob;
  3   delim varchar2(1) := '';
  4   amount int;
  5   sql_text varchar2(32767);
  6  BEGIN
  7  
  8    dbms_lob.createtemporary(sql_code,cache => true);
  9    sql_text := q'[CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB (X INT PRIMARY KEY, Y VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'DEF', Z INTEGER) PARTITION BY RANGE(Z) ( ]';
 10    amount := length(sql_text);
 11    dbms_lob.writeappend(sql_code,amount,sql_text);
 12  
 13    for i in 1..1024 loop
 14        sql_text := delim||'PARTITION P_'||i||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||i||')';
 15        amount := length(sql_text);
 16        dbms_lob.writeappend(sql_code,amount,sql_text);
 17        delim := ',';
 18    end loop;
 19  
 20    dbms_lob.writeappend(sql_code,1,')');
 21  
 22    FOR cur IN (
 23      SELECT * FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 24             SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'TEST_TAB')
 25    ) LOOP
 26      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_code;
 27    END LOOP;
 28  
 29    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getlength(lob_loc => sql_code));
 30  
 31  END;
 32  /
39877                                                                           

PL/SQL procedure completed.

SQL> desc test_tab
 Имя                                       Пусто?   Тип
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 X                                         NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 Y                                                  VARCHAR2(10)
 Z                                                  NUMBER(38)

SQL> select count(*) from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'TEST_TAB';

  COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
      1024
```

Comment: but it means i have to escape all the apostrophes in the ddls manually of create/find some tool for it

Comment: You can use q[''] Oracle syntax for character values to avoid manual work.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov, the alternative quoting syntax with brackets is `q'[]'`.

Comment: could you plz provide more details or a link to this `q['']` or `q'[]'`?

Comment: Please see Text Literal section: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617

Comment: i checked the `q'[]'`. it doesn't allow me to simply wrap the whole script. i got the error `Encountered the symbol "; END;" when...` and also the scrip cannot be larger than 4k. so it requires a lot of processing of the ddl script

Comment: DDL should not contain "; END;" - are you trying to cover whole  PL/SQL ? 4K should not be a limit - please see one more example in answer.